# How to Install re2c on Linux Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos7, rpm, yum, re2c

I was trying to install the Mailparse PECL extension with WHM/cPanel and it kept failing because re2c was missing.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the RPM from EPEL (you can use cURL): http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/r/re2c-0.14.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

`curl http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/r/re2c-0.14.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm --output re2c-0.14.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm`

2. Install the RPM

`rpm -Uvh re2c-0.14.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm`

3. That's it.